# Accessing Email Notifier settings in TeamCity

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I need to email the authors of individual nunit tests that are launched from within TeamCity when those tests fail, and I don't see a way to do this using the built-in [TeamCity notification-rules framework](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Subscribing+to+Notifications).

Specifically, we have a project that invokes a PowerShell script that launches a suite of Selenium- and nUnit-based integration tests as part of a TeamCity build and deploy. Each test is decorated with an Author attribute. If a test fails, I can parse the TestResult.xml output generated by nUnit. I can extract the author and email address of each failed test, but I can't figure out how to notify those test authors.

What I would like to do is pass the TeamCity global eMail notifier settings -- SMTP host, port, credentials, etc. -- to a Powershell script, but I don't know how to access those settings programmatically. Are those settings exposed as variables that can be passed as parameters to a Powershell script, and if so, how can I access them? Thanks!